# How to send data in secure way between two web applications on different servers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, session

Say I have `web application A on server1`& `web application B on server2`

and I want to send The following data From `A to B` Securely .

> (Employee number , salary key )

I can't use sessions here because they are two different applications  , and i don't want to send that data in the query string even if i encrypt them .

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you want to use the data. There are several options.

1. You can use WCF to send the data over a secure (HTTPS) connection. You can even secure the service with a client-side certificate, if you like.
2. You can pass the data via a database. Where one app writes the data to the database and the other application reads the data from the database.
3. You can use a queue like MSMQ, which is expensive or [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), which is open-source and free.
4. You can `POST` the data to the next page over `HTTPS` instead of using `GET` and putting the data in the quesry string.

p.s. If you do use the query string, you can make the next request over HTTPS, and that way it would be secure.

Comment: Could u provide some link to explain those ways in more details plz

Comment: If you can edit your question with more details about your specific scenario, I could help you out with more targeted advice (and other might be able to help as well).

Comment: It's a portal to multiple web applications , and i want to send authentication data from the portal to those application to make sure that the user is authenticated from the portal (The only entry point is the portal) so the user enter user name and password and see what should he see then when he clicks to enter any web application in the portal i want to send those data securely to that application .

Comment: Well you can make a custom service on the portal side that any of the sites can call to check if the user is authenticated. You could also use the `WS-Federation` standard, which is called `STS` in the `Microsoft` world. You need to look in to `Single Sign On` solutions for `.net`. No need to re-invent the wheel. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Federation